# MySQL: Limit a query to 10 rows where every index has 5 tags

Tags: php, mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to make a query where I can retrieve an interval of 10 rows with 5 tags per each one.

I have `houses` and `tags` table, I know how to do it only for simple queries with a `SELECT` using `LIMIT` but how can I do it in this case?

```
table houses
id    house            country
1     Grunt Mansion    us
2     Hororo Suneku    jp
3     Casa Cattani     it
4     Sweet Home       uk
5     Heinzvaiter      de
6     F56X-5           us
7     Swan Jong        cn
8     Drupnowevo       ru
9     Bambagiador      br
10    El Stanco        es

table houses_tags
id    id_house    id_tag
1     1           1
2     1           2
3     1           3
4     1           4
5     2           1
6     2           2
7     2           3
8     2           4

table tags
id    tag
1     minimal
2     baroque
3     cosy
4     simple
```

If a make a query like this to get the first 10 houses:

```
SELECT *
FROM houses
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM tags
    INNER JOIN houses_tags
    ON id_house = houses.id
    LIMIT 5
) house_tag
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I get something like this:

```
query result
row    house            country    tag      id_house     id_tag
1      Grunt Mansion    us         minimal  1            1
2      Grunt Mansion    us         baroque  1            2
3      Grunt Mansion    us         cosy     1            3
4      Grunt Mansion    us         simple   1            4
5      Hororo Suneku    jp         minimal  2            1
6      Hororo Suneku    jp         baroque  2            2
7      Hororo Suneku    jp         cosy     2            3
8      Hororo Suneku    jp         simple   2            4
9      Casa Cattani     it         NULL     NULL         NULL
10     Sweet Home       uk         NULL     NULL         NULL
```

My problem is I get only the first 10 rows cutting out the last `houses` from the query because the `tags` of the first ones occupy all the rows

Can I write a query where I can retrieve the first 10 houses and 5 tag per each one?

```
query result
row    house            country    tag      id_house     id_tag
1      Grunt Mansion    us         minimal  1            1
2      Grunt Mansion    us         baroque  1            2
3      Grunt Mansion    us         cosy     1            3
4      Grunt Mansion    us         simple   1            4
5      Hororo Suneku    jp         minimal  2            1
6      Hororo Suneku    jp         baroque  2            2
7      Hororo Suneku    jp         cosy     2            3
8      Hororo Suneku    jp         simple   2            4
9      Casa Cattani     it         NULL     NULL         NULL
10     Sweet Home       uk         NULL     NULL         NULL
11     Heinzvaiter      de         NULL     NULL         NULL
12     F56X-5           us         NULL     NULL         NULL
13     Swan Jong        cn         NULL     NULL         NULL
14     Drupnowevo       ru         NULL     NULL         NULL
15     Bambagiador      br         NULL     NULL         NULL
16     El Stanco        es         NULL     NULL         NULL
```

At the end I should need a result I display like this example:

```
Mansions          Tags
Grunt Mansion     minimal, baroque, cosy, simple
Hororo Suneku     minimal, baroque, cosy, simple
Casa Cattani      -
Sweet Home        -
Heinzvaiter       -
F56X-5            -
Swan Jong         -
Drupnowevo        -
Bambagiador       -
El Stanco         -

pages 1 | 2 | 3
```

can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have analytic functions, which is what you'd use for this before LIMIT:

```
    SELECT x.id,
           x.house,
           x.country,
           x.id_tag
      FROM (SELECT h.id,
                   h.house,
                   h.country,
                   ht.id_tag,
                   CASE 
                     WHEN @id = h.id THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                     ELSE @rownum := 1
                   END AS rank,
                   @id := h.id,
                   @house_count := @house_count + 1 AS house_count
              FROM HOUSE h
         LEFT JOIN HOUSES_TAGS ht ON ht.id_house = h.id
              JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id := -1, @house_count := 0) r
          ORDER BY h.id, ht.id_tag) x
   WHERE x.house_count <= 10
     AND x.rank <= 4        
ORDER BY x.id, x.id_tag
```

Comment: Thanks for help, can you also help me to understand CASE and @vars syntax with some explanation link, it would be very useful to me.

Comment: @Vittorio Vittori: The MySQL [CASE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html); @variable_name is a variable.  I use the cartesian product--`JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id := -1, @house_count := 0) r`--to define the variables without needing a separate `SET` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your subselect to give you back the 10 houseID's you want results for, then just left join against the tags table subselect (limit 5)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but It doesn't seems to change the result, my problem starts beacuse I'd like to get an interval of 10 houses including 5 tags per each one, for example if I use LIMIT 0, 10 at the end of the query I thought MySql returned me the result without counting the subselect rows, but it seems to do it. I dunno If I've been clear (i hope!)